# How to simulate a coin flip with While... Wend and Do... Until?

Tags: excel, vba, coin-flipping

Develop a solution to flip a coin a given amount of times and then print the number of heads and the number of tail. The equation to toss the coin is

`Coin = Integer(random*2) + 1`

When Coin = 1 the toss is heads, and when Coin = 2 the toss is tails.

Random returns a number between 0 and 1, including 0, but not 1.

Therefore, when random is less than 0.5, Coin will equal 1; and when random is greater than or equal to 0.5 and less than 1, Coin will equal 2.

Structure: While... wend and Do... Until

I've done For Next structure, but I have trouble turning it into those structures.

```
Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer
heads = 0
tails = 0 
flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0
For i = 1 To flips
    If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
        tails = tails + 1
    Else 
        heads = heads + 1
    End If
Next i 
MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")
```

Comment: show your code up to now. and.. what course is this from?

Comment: is this homework or something?

Comment: my course  is Computer Programming algorithms

Comment: what does your instructor say about how to learn it? does he say to come here? or does he give you a lesson plan of some sort and instructions?

Comment: Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer

heads = 0
tails = 0
flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0

For i = 1 To flips
    If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
        tails = tails + 1
    Else
        heads = heads + 1
    End If
Next i

MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")

Comment: This is the one I am trying to convert. Yes, it is a homework, but I have tried it for days, but it does not work and the teacher only said to keep trying and did not give me any idea of what could be my mistake.

Comment: I put your code in the question (in wait of edit approval). Remembere to always put your code in the question and don't leave it in comments

Comment: He just gave me a class on how to make those structs, but with a simple example. I discovered this page.

Comment: see these links for [While..Wend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement) and [Do... Until](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Loops

**The principle**

```
' For
For i = 1 To flips
    '...
Next i

' While
i = 0 ' by default
While i < flips
    i = i + 1
    '...
Wend

' Do (1)
i = 0 ' by default
Do Until i = flips
    i = i + 1
    '...
Loop


' Do (2)
i = 0 ' by default
Do
    i = i + 1
    '...
Loop Until i = flips
```

**Applied**

```
Sub flipsFor()
    Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0
    ' For
    For i = 1 To flips
        If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
            tails = tails + 1
        Else
            heads = heads + 1
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")
End Sub
Sub flipsWhile()
    Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0
    ' While
    i = 0 ' by default
    While i < flips
        i = i + 1
        If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
            tails = tails + 1
        Else
            heads = heads + 1
        End If
    Wend
    MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")
End Sub

Sub flipsDo1()
    Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0
    ' Do (1)
    i = 0 ' by default
    Do Until i = flips
        i = i + 1
        If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
            tails = tails + 1
        Else
            heads = heads + 1
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")
End Sub

Sub flipsDo2()
    Dim flips As Integer, heads As Integer, tails As Integer, i As Integer
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    flips = InputBox("How many flips?") + 0
    ' Do (2)
    i = 0 ' by default
    Do
        i = i + 1
        If (Rnd * 2) + 1 >= 0.5 And (Rnd * 2) < 1 Then
            tails = tails + 1
        Else
            heads = heads + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = flips
    MsgBox (heads & " heads, " & tails & " tails.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, you have helped me a lot.